# node js consulta sincronica

Tags: mysql, nodejs, api

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta a una base de datos **mysql** despues de obtener unos id de otra consulta, pero me envia el `callback` en blanco osea responde antes de terminar la consulta a la bd no se como solucionarlo.

```
   imgmodule.darImagenesServ = (row,callback)=>
    {
      if(connection)
      {
          console.log('antes del ciclo');
              for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
              {
                console.log('en el ciclo');
                var serv = row[i];
                var id = serv.idservicios;
                var sql = 'SELECT * FROM fotos where servicios_idservicios = ?';
                  connection.query(sql,[id],(err,resp)=>
                  {
                    console.log(id);
                     row.fotos = resp;
                    //codigo que crga la nueva consulta al json row
                  });
              }
              callback(null,row)
      }
    };
```

Cambie el codigo por este

```
if(connection)
{
  var sql = 'SELECT servicios.* FROM servicios ORDER BY calificacion asc;';
  connection.query(sql,(err,row)=>{
if(err)
{

}
else
{
  var p =0;
    return new Promise((resolv,reject)=>{
      var sql = 'SELECT * FROM fotos where servicios_idservicios = ?';
      var jsonServ = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        {
          var serv = row[i];
          console.log(i);
          id = serv.idservicios;
          connection.query(sql,[id],(err,resp)=>{
            console.log('consulta bd');
            if(err){throw err}
            else {
              serv.foto = resp;
              //console.log('///////*****///////');
              console.log(serv);
              jsonServ.push(serv);
              p++;
              if(p==row.length)
              {
                band=true;
                console.log('final ciclo');

                if(band==true)
                {
                //resolv(jsonServ);
                callback(null,jsonServ);
                }


              }
                }
          });

      }

    });

}
  });

  }
  console.log('prueba');
};
```

y hace primero el recorrido del ciclo y luego hace la consulta a la base de datos da un resultado asi:

```
servicios
prueba
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
consulta bd
RowDataPacket {
  idservicios: 15,
  nombre: 'fotos fots y mas fotos',
  descripcion: 'prueba de fotos',
  duracion: 25,
  max_citas_ves: 2,
  video: 'http://www.youtube.com//ashd89u98',
  calificacion: 3,
  provedores_id: 1780508912002126,
  municipio_id_municipio: 13301,
  foto: [] }
consulta bd
RowDataPacket {
  idservicios: 15,
  nombre: 'fotos fots y mas fotos',
  descripcion: 'prueba de fotos',
  duracion: 25,
  max_citas_ves: 2,
  video: 'http://www.youtube.com//ashd89u98',
  calificacion: 3,
  provedores_id: 1780508912002126,
  municipio_id_municipio: 13301,
  foto: [] }
consulta bd
RowDataPacket {
  idservicios: 15,
  nombre: 'fotos fots y mas fotos',
  descripcion: 'prueba de fotos',
  duracion: 25,
  max_citas_ves: 2,
  video: 'http://www.youtube.com//ashd89u98',
  calificacion: 3,
  provedores_id: 1780508912002126,
  municipio_id_municipio: 13301,
  foto:
   [ RowDataPacket {
       id: 4,
       nombre:
        'IMG_20171129_163708_resized_1jpgGjkotBxnr4CadtxGMS0C4esy.jpg',
       ruta:
        '/servicios/IMG_20171129_163708_resized_1jpgGjkotBxnr4CadtxGMS0C4esy.jpg',
       servicios_idservicios: 12 } ] }
consulta bd
```

osea ase la consulta con el ultimo id que tomas en el ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

Responde antes porque una vez recorrido `row` se ejecuta el callback y el siguiente bloque de código se ejecuta de manera asíncrona (el callback se puede ejecutar sin necesidad de esperar a que respondan las queries)

```
connection.query(sql, [id], (err,resp) => {
    console.log(id);
    row.fotos = resp;
    //codigo que crga la nueva consulta al json row
});
```

Por lo que tendrías que ejecutar el callback una vez hayan terminado de ejecutarse todas las queries.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuzmanE de Igual manera estas ejecutando una función asincrona dentro del `for`. El `for` se ejecuta de manera síncrona, por lo que no le interesa esperar a que la funcion `connection.query` termine de ejecutarse (ya que estas quedan dentro del stack del event loop). Para poder solucionar tu problemas, podrías usar async/await (si es que utilizas una version de node que lo soporte) o el método `each` la librería async http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each